# Conflict of Interest Disclosure Determination Form - Do I need a disclosure form if I stopped working the contracted position before the new job?

Tags: human-resources, contractors

For my new job (not as a contractor), my employee packet includes a question about whether I am "currently engaged or intend to engage" in a different job. I can verify that I have not worked for nor earned payments from my previous employer - as a contractor -  since I started the new job, but the contracted position is available to me until September.

> Since I am listed as a contractor until next month, should I say "no"?

In case I was to disclose information about my contracted position, I have some related follow-up questions.

In addition, the form wants a yes or no answer response to "employee-vendor relationship is not substantial (is not over $1000)."

> Before my new job started, I earned over $1000 as a contractor. However, I have earned $0 upon starting the new job. Can I say that the relationship is less than $1000?

Comment: @TheSubstitute are you filling some sort of form? Do you have fixed options (yes/no) or is there room to write and explain?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'll edit the post to address that

Comment: What does "have access to the contracted position" mean? Does this mean you can do work and get paid when you want? If you have no intention of doing work, I think it's justified to say "no". But you should consider writing to your previous vendor and severing that relationship properly rather than letting it lapse.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, it means that I can log into a website to earn money from the previous vendor until September.

Answer (score 3):

> the new employee packet includes a part that inquires whether we are
> "currently engaged or intend to engage" in a different job. My answer
> to their question is no, but I am not sure if having access to the
> contracted position for another month says otherwise.

IMHO, you should have answered "Yes". You are still "currently engaged" in a different job until September.

Perhaps you could explain the situation and why you will not do any further contracting work, even though you could until September.

> In addition, the form wants a yes or no answer response to
> "employee-vendor relationship is not substantial (is not over $1000)."
>
> Before my new job started, I earned over $1000 as a contractor.
> However, I have earned $0 upon starting the new job. Can I say that
> the relationship is less than $1000?

This has nothing to do with a vendor, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

> For my new job (not as a contractor), my employee packet includes a
> question about whether I am "currently engaged or intend to engage" in
> a different job... contracted position is available to me until
> September.

For me, the term engaged means if you are actively working and/or receiving a pay check.

Having some sort of agreement which means you are able to work is not the same as working.

If the question was about being under an employment contract, I would have said yes, as you are under a contract, and the contract is related to employment.